# Application of Itô's formula

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $(W)_{t\ge0}$ and $(B)_{t\ge0}$ be independent Brownian motions.

Consider $X_t=\exp(-W_t)\left(x_0+\int_0^t\exp(W_s)dB_s\right)$.

Can anyone explain to me how to obtain

$dX_t=dB_t+X_t\left(\frac{1}{2}dt-dW_t\right)$

via Itô's formula?

Comment: Hint: write $Y_t=exp(-W_t)$ and $Z_t=\left(x_0+\int_0^t\exp(W_s)dB_s\right)$ and use the Ito's formula for a product.

Comment: Is $\langle Y,Z \rangle_t=\langle \int_0^t -\exp(-W_s)dW_s+\int_0^t \exp(-W_s)ds,x+\int_0^t \exp(W_s) dB_s\rangle=-\int_0^t d\langle B,W\rangle_t=-\langle B,W\rangle_t=0$

Comment: I cannot post a comment with less than 15 character, nevertheless the answer is yes.